# What to use for public key certificate validation, Certificate Depository via LDAP or an OCSP responder?

Tags: pki

So i was sniffing through the pages of PKI's Overview by Joel Weise (http://highsecu.free.fr/db/outils_de_securite/cryptographie/pki/publickey.pdf) and one thing i didn't quite get is, when to use an OCSP responder over LDAP for checking up the validity of a given certificate ? Say some CA exposes both - when to use the OCSP service, when to use the Certificate Depositories LDAP servers ?

Answer (score 3):

It might be helpful to think this way.

The Certificate Authority generates certificate revocation lists (CRLs).  (You could query the CA directly but this is a bad idea due to risk of exposing private keys (secrets)).

The CRLs can then be made available via LDAP or HTTP. (if you have a small deployment you can likely stop here)

An OCSP server (or validation authority depending on the vernacular) can also consume CRLs.  Once it does so it can handle validation (certificate status) requests. (if you have a larger deployment and handling CRLs is cumbersome you might consider this option)

There are options (3rd parties, e.g. not Microsoft) for there to be distributed OCSP responders that have pre-signed the responses and then forward and store (as opposed to multiple OCSP servers).  (consider if you still have a relatively larger deployment and where you have network availability, scale, loading issues as another option).

Finally make sure that you are not only checking certificate status but also certificate trust.  In federated environments you may want to consider the Server Certificate Validation Protocol (SCVP) as a complement to the above.